# Using Environment Variables to initialise MySQL connection in NextJS leads to 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE' error

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, dotenv

I am trying to fetch data from a MySQL table. It works perfectly when I hardcode the configuration. But when I use env variables to configure it, I get the following error:

```
  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true
```

This is my .env.local file:

```
MYSQL_HOST: localhost
MYSQL_USER: root
MYSQL_PASSWORD:************
MYSQL_DB:***
```

this is my db connections code:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
});
db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("connected to db");
  }
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: I have tried this. No change.

Comment: @juliomalves I'm stupid. I used ':' instead of '='.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I used ':' instead of '='.

Comment: seems like user issue.